# Command return a list, should be parsed

Tags: bash, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, do-while

I have shell program which returns a list:

```
list-all-my-users.sh
```

the result is:

```
username1
username2
username3
username4
username5
```

Now I would like to use the result in another programm

```
ldapsearch -D "adminuser" -w "password" -p 389 -h server.domain.de -b "DC=ORG,DC=com" -s sub "(&(objectclass=person)(cn=<USERNAME))" | grep employeeID: | awk '{print $2}'
```

Can me show someone an example ? I would like to avoid to save results in textfiles and parse them.

```
while(list-all-my-users.sh)
{
   foreach result
   {
      # LDAPSearch
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop

```
while read username
do
ldapsearch -D "adminuser" -w "password" \
           -p 389 -h server.domain.de \
           -b "DC=ORG,DC=com" \
           -s sub "(&(objectclass=person)(cn=${username}))" | 
           awk '/employeeID:/{print $2}'
done<list-all-my-users.sh
```

As you might have noticed, we are passing each result from `list-all-my-users.sh` to `ldapsearch` using the `${username}` variable. Also, you need not use `grep` and `awk` together. Instead, search for the pattern in `awk` using `/pattern/` construct.